# Adding new item to a listItem (drop down list) on google Forms using apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there a way to add a new item to a listItem (drop down list) in the new Google Forms using apps script?

I have a google form which has a listItem with many choices:

EX.: Your color
       - red
       - blue
       - white
       - green

I would like to be able to add a new choice, say "black", to this list using apps script. I know it's possible to add it directly on the form, but the use case needs the choice to be added via apps script.

I tried to use the setChoices() function but this will override the current list with the new choice. I would like to add/append the new choice to the list.

Do you guys know a way to achieve this?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `getChoices()` to get a copy of the existing list and append the choice.

```
choices = listItem.getChoices();
choices.push(listItem.createChoice('black'));
listitem.setChoices(choices);
```